# how to make touchablehighlight remain dark when tapped on?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

how do I make touchablehighlight buttons to remain dark when clicked on? And when clicked on again, they turn back to their original shade.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it dark or bright with transparency adjustments. If you want to change color, you can change color.

```js
  state={
    check : false,
    opacity : 0.2
  }

  onpress = () => {
    if (!this.state.check) {
      this.setState({
        opacity : 0.2,
        check: true
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        opacity : 1,
        check: false
      })
    }
  }

<TouchableHighlight style={{alignItems:"center", backgroundColor: "black", opacity: this.state.opacity }} onPress={() => this.onpress()}>
  <Text style={{color: "#ffffff"}}>TouchableHighlight</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

[image]

> You can use  multiple inline style

```js
<TouchableHighlight style={[styles.touchablehighlight ,{ opacity: this.state.opacity }]} onPress={() => this.onpress()}>
```

Comment: you cannot access this.state from stylesheet

Comment: @lilyfromtheblock You can use multiple inline style. I have attached the usage method.